# VB.NET Read 2 checkboxes status from file

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I am trying to recover the status of 2 checkboxes.
This 2 checkboxes i made them to work as radiobuttun: While one is checked, the another one uncheck.

I have an external file for the configuration of the program and i want that evrytime that I exit from the program, everything be saved in this file.

For do it I use this code:

```
   Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing

    Dim thefile As String = Application.StartupPath & "\SafetyBox.cfg"
    Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(thefile)

    lines(1) = "Language_file=" & ComboBox1.Text
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        lines(2) = "Status1=" & "1"
    Else
        lines(2) = "Status1=" & "0"
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        lines(3) = "Status2=" & "1"
    Else
        lines(3) = "Status2=" & "0"
    End If
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(thefile, lines)

End Sub`
```

And this part working great. Status1 should be the status of checkbox1, while status2 is the status of checkbox2.

The code that is not working is:

```
 Dim path As String = Application.StartupPath & "\SafetyBox.cfg"
    If File.Exists(path) Then

        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path)

            Dim linenew As String = sr.ReadLine()
            If linenew.Contains("\") Then
                TextBox1.Text = linenew



            Else
                MsgBox("Configura il programma da usare")
            End If

            Dim lineN As String = sr.ReadLine()
            If lineN.Contains("Language_file=") Then
                ComboBox1.Text = lineN.Split("=").Last()
            End If
            If lineN.Contains("Status1=1") Then
                CheckBox1.Checked = True
                CheckBox2.Checked = False

            ElseIf lineN.contains("Status1=0") Then
                CheckBox1.Checked = False
                CheckBox2.Checked = True

            End If



            If lineN.Contains("Status2=1") Then
                CheckBox1.Checked = False
                CheckBox2.Checked = True

            ElseIf lineN.Contains("Status2=0") Then
                CheckBox1.Checked = True
                CheckBox2.Checked = False
            End If
                sr.ReadToEnd()
            sr.Close()
        End Using
```

Can yOu let me understnd where is my mistake? Why when in the .cfg file is wrote correctly Status1=0 and Status2=1, when loading the program i always see checkbox1 checkd and not checkbox2?

Thanks

Comment: If the `CheckBoxes` are being used like `RadioButtons` then why are you not using `RadioButtons`? Also, if the states are always opposite, why do you need to save two values?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick answer. I don't used radiobutton, because they was complicated me the life in this case.

Comment: There's nothing complex about `RadioButtons`. The only reason I can see that you wouldn't use them if you wanted the behaviour they provide is if you wanted the two controls on different parent controls.  Only `RadioButtons` with the same parent act as a group. Of course, if that is the reason then that's probably what you ought to have said when I asked why you weren't using them.

Comment: That second code snippet is rather terrible. I'm not sure why you don't call `File.ReadAllLines` like you do in the first snippet. That would most likely simplify things to the point where you wouldn't be making the mistake that you are.

Comment: Sorry, my comment up started befor i finished Hi. Thanks for the quick answer. I don't used radiobutton, because they was complicated me the life in this case. The program is in multilanguage. there are several language file and also the user can create and translate for his own language, so will have to save 2 values because personally i did not found alternative with my limitate experience. If you have ny suggestions, will be great. Thanks again for help :)

Comment: That said, you should be able to find the mistake for yourself by debugging the code.  When you have an issue, DO NOT simply read the code. Execute it and watch it in action by setting a breakpoint and stepping through it. It's why VS has a debugger.  Learn how [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you so much for your advices they helped me so much and finally that code is working. I changed the second code snippet  an make it looking like the first and works great. I Am not a programmer of course. The little things I know, are from ebooks and hours and hours of self training trying to realize something for my self, but ad a match with myself too. Because of that I really appreciated your strong criticism and the way you addressed me on the solution. Someone can tell that your answer was arrogant,  but I think that was the answer of a teacher helping a new student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that you got the `CheckBoxes` working as `RadionButtons`. I suspect that to do this you handled either or both of the events `CheckedChanged` and `CheckStateChanged`.

So that when the CheckState is changed, the other Checkbox is set or unset appropriately.

When you load the configuration/state of the form from the file, you are setting the values on the CheckBoxes and subsequently, causing the events to be fired. To prevent the events from being fired you should temporarily remove the event handlers from the Checkbox controls.

Add the lines at the start of your method to load the configuration:

```
RemoveHandler Checkbox1.CheckStateChanged, AddressOf Checkbox1_CheckStateChanged
RemoveHandler Checkbox2.CheckStateChanged, AddressOf Checkbox2_CheckStateChanged
```

And, at the end of the method, you will need to re-establish the event handlers by using:

```
AddHandler Checkbox1.CheckStateChanged, AddressOf Checkbox1_CheckStateChanged
AddHandler Checkbox2.CheckStateChanged, AddressOf Checkbox2_CheckStateChanged
```

If this is the problem, what you have encountered is a common enough problem when a form has multiple event handlers that respond to `xxxChanged` events.